# How to make automatic categories in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make categories for this table:

| mentor_id | month_dt | avg_sessions_per_week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3802 | 01.09.2022 | 15.00 |
| 772 | 01.09.2022 | 10.00 |
| 3105 | 01.09.2022 | 8.00 |
| 4123 | 01.09.2022 | 8.00 |
| 3347 | 01.09.2022 | 7.00 |
| 884 | 01.09.2022 | 6.00 |
| 2928 | 01.09.2022 | 6.00 |
| 1482 | 01.09.2022 | 4.00 |

I can make categories by using case.
Something like this:

```
case
    when avg_sessions_per_week >= 10 then '10 - 15 sessions'
    when avg_sessions_per_week >= 4 then '4 - 9 sessions'
end as category
```

But how I can make it automatic, without hardcoding?

Comment: Well, at some point you need to hard code the values in the `then` branch, especially if they don't have the same length for each.

Comment: Yep, I've just make some changes in question, so categories should have same length.

Comment: They don't, `select 15 - 10; 5` vs `select 9 - 5; 4`.

Comment: Oh, I've been nattentive. I've corrected my question. =/

Answer (score 0):

By making a lookup table that maps categories to a sessions range:

```
create table session_category (category varchar, session_range  int4range);

insert into session_category 
    values ('5 - 6 sessions', int4range(5, 6, '[]')), 
           ('7 - 9 sessions', int4range(7, 9, '[]')), 
           ('10 - 15 sessions', int4range(10, 15, '[]'));

select category from session_category where 7 <@ session_range;
 category    
----------------
 7 - 9 sessions
```

This uses [Ramge type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) to build an integer range for the session endpoints. FYI, the `'[]'` makes the upper endpoint inclusive instead of the default for `int4range` which is exclusive. Then find where the `avg_sessions_per_week`(7 in this case) value falls in the ranges using `<@` and return the associated category.